# create object chaining using loop

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Is there a way to create a chained object from loop?
For example input:

```
["table1","table2","table3"]
```

output:

```
  db
  .select(fields)
  .from(table)
  .innerJoin("table1")
  .innerJoin("table2")
  .innerJoin("table3")
```

another input:

```
 ["table1","table2","table3","table4","table5"]
```

output:

```
  db
  .select(fields)
  .from(table)
  .innerJoin("table1")
  .innerJoin("table2")
  .innerJoin("table3")
  .innerJoin("table4")
  .innerJoin("table5")
```

Right now i have no idea how to do that except using eval, which isn't something i would like to do.

I need this to join multiple tables using knex, so if there any other way to do so, i will be really happy :)

Comment: are you wanting code generation i.e output a string that looks like that or just the overall outcome?

Comment: @JoeWarner thank you for asking, i forgot to clarify that i need overall outcome not the actual chained object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think looking into functional programming will help you here.

I used a pipe function from the internet link below but you could use lodash/Ramda/underscore or whatever your fav util library is.

the two main concepts I'm using here is currying and piping.

> [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) Currying is when you break down a function that takes multiple arguments into a series of functions that take part of the arguments
>   we are also making use of curring which is returning a function from another function to compose new functions.
>
> https://medium.com/@venomnert/pipe-function-in-javascript-8a22097a538e A pipe function takes an n sequence of operations; in which each operation takes an argument; process it; and gives the processed output as an input for the next operation in the sequence. The result of a pipe function is a function that is a bundled up version of the sequence of operations.

what we're doing here is taking an array, creating a new array of functions we want to apply to a value.

So we want to do a load of joins on a db.

`join => con => con.innerJoin(join);`

is taking a value i.e "table1" and returning a function that takes a db connection which calls the join and returns for the next one.

`const joins = toJoin.map(join => con => con.innerJoin(join));`
and this creates are array of functions to pass to pipe.

```js
const db = ({
  select: function (field) {
    console.log('select', field)
    return db
  },
  from: function (table) {
    console.log('from', table)
    return db;
  },
  innerJoin: function (join) {
    console.log('innerJoin', join)
    return db;
  }
});

const _pipe = (a, b) => (arg) => b(a(arg));
const pipe = (args) => [].slice.apply(args).reduce(_pipe);

function joinInnerMultiple(table, fields, toJoin) {
  const joins = toJoin.map(join => con => con.innerJoin(join));

  return pipe(joins)(db.select(fields).from(table)); 
}


joinInnerMultiple("User", "uuid", ["table1", "table2", "table3", "table4", "table5"])
```

Comment: whoever downvoted mine explaining, if I've misunderstood happy to change.

Comment: Quite honestly, I think a simple “for” loop would do in this case. Your answer seems too complex. Passion for FP is great, but it might create more confusion for the OP than value.

Comment: this is more coming from the point of view of chaing loads of differnet functions but yeah would be overkill in this instance.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.
Note for knex users: db object is a knex connection object

Comment: awesome glad to help :) any questions let me know

Answer (score 3):

The way chaining works is that each of those methods returns an object that has the next method as a property. This means you can use something like [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to keep calling the next method on the object returned from the previous.

`reduce()` accepts an initial object, which you can pass to get things rolling. Something like:

```
var tables = ["table1","table2","table3"]
let res = tables.reduce((res, table) => res.innerJoin(table), db.select(fields).from(table))
```

To get a sense how this works we can create a fake `db` object with all the methods that return the object for the next method in the chain. The `innerJoin` method just adds the argument to the value property:

```js
// fake db object with these methods
const db = {
  select(t) {
    this.val = [] // initialize val
    return this
  },
  from(t) {
    return this
  },
  innerJoin(name) {
    this.val.push("Added: " + name)
    return this
  }
}

var tables = ["table1","table2","table3"]
// call innerjoin for each of the tables
// this is the same as chaining them
let res = tables.reduce((res, table) => res.innerJoin(table), db.select().from())

// values where accumlated in the val property
console.log(res.val)
```

Comment: nice solution this is much better than mine when applying just one type of function.

Comment: I've tried this solution and unfortunately it didn't work with knex db object, however without knex this works just fine.

Comment: this might  be beause the reduce creates a new object? i dunno tho

Comment: `reduce()` doesn't necessarily return a new object @JoeWarner — it returns the object returned by the reducer function which in this case it the last invocation of `innerJoin()`. I'm not sure why this isn't working with knex — it seems like it should be identical to chaining.

Comment: yeah totally im confused also might try find out why

Comment: Sorry for misguidance, when i had tried your solution i made a mistake with db object. Turns out your solutions works just fine aswell.